# JavaScript prototype.init craziness

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain the significance of prototype.init function in JavaScript and when it is called during object instantiation?

Why would you want to overwrite it with an empty function?

I am reading the JavaScript for Web book and am stuck on the this for the past few hours...what is piece of code supposed to achieve?

```
var Class = function(){ 

var klass = function(){
   this.init.apply(this, arguments); 
};

klass.prototype.init = function(){};

// Shortcut to access prototype 
klass.fn = klass.prototype;

// Shortcut to access class 
klass.fn.parent = klass;

...
}
```

This is just too much magic for me...:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure what you don't understand. `init` is simply a method like any other, that happens to be called in the constructor and with the same parameters as the constructor. If it's empty then it's just because the person who wrote it didn't need to put anything in it for now but wanted to lay down the groundworks of his class.

```
function Foo(a, b, c) {
    this.init.apply(this, arguments); //This simply calls init with the arguments from Foo
}

Foo.prototype.init = function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

var f = new Foo(1, 2, 3); //prints 1 2 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hmgch/

Comment: This is exactly right. `init` is not special in JavaScript; it is just this author's strange choice to delegate constructor work to this `init` function.

Comment: Thanks. I have not done JS since 2001...it has been a while and these things were not even around back then :) What really spooked me is my false understanding that init was significant in object creation by default. Author uses weird terminology which is not helping...

Comment: @Moonwalker indeed, the language has evolved a lot

Answer (score 3):

> what is piece of code supposed to achieve?

Confusion.

```
var Class = function() { 
  // initialization logic
}

// Shortcut to access prototype 
Class.fn = klass.prototype;

// Shortcut to access class 
Class.fn.constructor = Class;
```

Comment: Indeed - your mind starts going in circles...from what I understand prototype.constructor has absolutely zero significance as well..  The author talks about static methods at the class level and instance method at prototype level - sounds like it is a little backwards....

Comment: @Moonwalker `prototype.constructor` is really important for meta programming. For example `instance2 = new (instance1.constructor)();`